# How to get Internet connection working (restarting networking and network-manager does nothing)?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

My Internet connection is not working since I restarted my laptop (which is very old). Here's what I've tried:

1. Ran `sudo -s` then tried `/etc/init.d/networking stop`:

   ```
   * Deconfiguring network interfaces...
   Root@carlos-laptop: ~#
   ```
2. Ran `status networking`:

   ```
   Networking stop/waiting
   ```
3. Ran `status network-manager`:

   ```
   network-manager start/running, process 621
   ```
4. Running `restart networking` gives me: `restart: unknown instance:`
5. I successfully restarted network-manager.
6. Ran `/etc/init.d/networking start`.

   It says I should instead use the service(8) utility and "*since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an upstart job, you may also use the service(8)... ...networking stop/waiting*".
7. Tried `ifup eth0` and got `ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0`

   `ifdown eth0` gave: `interface eth0 not configured`
8. Then I configured `/etc/network/interfaces` in nano.

   Specifically, I deleted `loopback lo` and inserted `eth0`.

   Then I ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. (By this point i thought it would work, but i was wrong.) I got:

   ```
   *reconfiguring network interfaces...
   Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3
   Copyright...bla all rights reserved
   ```

   ```
   Listening on LPF/eth0/00:90:f5:4d:f8:ed
   Sending on --as above--
   Sending on Socket/fallback
   DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4;6;7;14;19;11
   No DHCPOFFERS recevied.
   No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
   ```
9. I tried to `ping www.google.com` and got `ping: unknown host www.google.com`.
10. Ran `dpkg --configure -a` which gave:

    ```
    Setting up libsdl-ttf2.0-0 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
    Errors were encountered while processing: 
        libsdl-ttf2.0-0
    ```
11. Tried `restart networking` again:

    ```
    There is already a pid file /var/run/dgclient.eth0.pid with pid 1811 killed old client process, removed PID file
    ```

    Internet Systems ...
    Got the same answer- no DHCPOFFERS received.
12. Started Firefox, went to Google:

    ```
    -XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
    Location: jar:file///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/etError.xhtml
    Line number 23, Column 51:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/s
    ```
13. Tried to restart the laptop, and got nothing again.
14. Ran `route -n`:

    ```
    Destination 169.254.0.0
    Gateway 0.0.0.0
    Genmask 255.255.0.0
    Flags metric ref U     0      0
    Use Iface 0 eth0
    ```
15. Did `sudo dhclient eth0`, got: `no DHCPOFFERS received`
16. Restarted again, opened `/etc/network/interfaces`. It was empty. `NetworkingManager.conf` is also empty.

I don't know what to do. I am so frustrated right now and have been writing this for an hour on my friend's iPhone. So if you can, help me, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into `/etc/network/interfaces` and reboot the computer:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: No need to restart though, you can run `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` after making the edits. That's for ubuntu 14.04, in prior versions you can run `sudo service networking restart`.